# I want to redirect 301 by htaccess with 2 parameters in the destination link

Tags: linux, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all pdf file on my host to other host:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /pdf/(.*)$ http://myhost.com/main_fs_1.jsp?P_SYS=6&P_LANGU=E
```

On my localhost (XAMPP on MAC) is working ok but on the Linux host, it did not redirect to `http://myhost.com/main_fs_1.jsp?P_LANGU=E&P_SYS=6`

Example I enter

```
oldhost.com/pdf/myfile.pdf
```

It will be redirect to:

```
http:// myhost.com/main_fs_1.jsp?P_LANGU=E/pdf/myfile.pdfP_SYS=6
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You tag with php, where is the php in this question?

Comment: your title doesn't pre-describe your question sufficient. And why is there php tagged but not Linux? Please have a close look to your question and edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I found the solution:
please add a slash in to this line:
RedirectMatch 301 /pdf/(.*)$ http://myhost.com/main_fs_1.jsp?P_SYS=6&P_LANGU=E 
it must be
RedirectMatch 301 /pdf/(.*)$ http://myhost.com/main_fs_1.jsp?P_SYS=6\&P_LANGU=E

Hope that this help you too.